# How to test that a view helper renders a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, view-helpers, specs

Say I want to render different partials depending on an instance variable from the controller. I put the logic in a helper method, that looks something like:

```
def display_my_partial(foo)
  foo == bar ? render(partial_x) : render(partial_y)
end
```

and in the view I call (using Slim):

```
= display_my_partial(@foo)
```

What should my test look like? I tried something like:

```
expect(display_my_partial(foo)).to render(partial: 'partial_x')
```

but got:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `matches?' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007ffb490aba80>
```

My example is a bit more complicated, as my partials are in a nested namespace. I had to experiment a little with just usind `render 'partial_x'` vs `render partial: 'namespace/model/partial_x'` to get it working in the specs, but finally I got the above mentioned error.

So how would you test this?

Comment: Why not test content of partial instead of controller helper?

Comment: Because I don't know if its a good practice to test views in helper specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you testing it in? Make sure render_views is called.

In any case, do you *really* care it's rendering that partial? What if the file name is changed, or you decide to change the implementation using html helpers instead. None of this matters to the output. I would personally assert the output instead. Depending on how complex the output is you could do it in a view test or just simple unit tests.

HTH,

Comment: Well I am testing this in the model_helpers_spec.rb, so `render_views` will not work. That's the things - it's outside the context of a controller and this is why I find it hard to determine how to test it.

Comment: I didn't, I've skipped this test.